# The Rust trait for operators seems to be more complex than necessary. Why?

Tags: rust

Rust defines some standard traits for operators, as members of `std`.

Here is one such example:

```
trait Add<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;

    fn add(self: Self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Here is an example implementation.

```
/// Note: Type `i32` has been chosen here
/// rather than a generic `T` for clarity
impl Add for Complex<i32> {
    type Output = Complex<i32>;

    fn add(self: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        Complex {
            re: self.re + rhs.re,
            im: self.im + rhs.im
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that there is redundant information contained within the definition of the `trait Add`. For example, there is no reason to store the type `Self` in a new name `Output`.

Here is an example, which avoids doing so:

```
use num::complex::Complex;

trait MyAdd<Rhs = Self> {
    
    fn myAdd(self: Self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self;
}

impl MyAdd for Complex<i32> {
    
    fn myAdd(self: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        
        Complex {
            re: self.re + rhs.re,
            im: self.im + rhs.im,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
    
    let c1: Complex<i32> = Complex::new(1, 0);
    let c2: Complex<i32> = Complex::new(0, -1);
    
    let c3: Complex<i32> = c1.myAdd(c2);
    
    println!("{:?}", c3);
}
```

So my question is this: *Why does the `Add` trait store the related type in `Output`?* What is the advantage or purpose of this?

Comment: Pretty sure this is covered in [chapter 19 of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html).

Comment: A + B could give C that fully generic.

Comment: What if A + B = some other type C? Like `i32 + i32 = i64` is something you could trivially implement if you have the `Output` option. Without that it'd be very hard to work around.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you're implementing computations on intervals. I.e. you have a `struct Interval(usize, usize)`.

Now, you want to be able to "add" two intervals -- which simply results in another interval whose bounds are the respective sums:

```
impl Add for Interval {
    type Output = Interval;
    fn add(self, rhs: Interval) -> Self::Output {
        Interval(self.0+rhs.0, self.1+rhs.1)
    }
}
```

Now assume you want to be able to write `interval + 42` to offset both interval bounds by 42. Rust supports this by implementing `Add` as follows:

```
impl Add<usize> for Interval {
    type Output = Interval;
    fn add(self, rhs: usize) -> Self::Output {
        self + Interval(rhs, rhs) // delegate to <Interval as Add<Interval>>::add
    }
}
```

Until now, you could go with your `MyAdd`.

But now, we want to be able to write `42 + interval` (i.e. shifting 42 by two different values). In this case, `Self` is `usize`, but the resulting `Output` is an interval:

```
impl Add<Interval> for usize {
    type Output = Interval;
    fn add(self, rhs: Interval) -> Self::Output {
        rhs + self // delegate to <Interval as Add<usize>>::add
    }
}
```

Admittedly, this example may be contrived, but it showcases why it might be useful to have `Rhs` and `Output` independent.

There *may* even be cases where `Self`, `Rhs` and `Output` are all distinct, e.g. when you want to add a `Complex` to your `Interval` -- in this case it will result in a `GenericInterval<Complex>`:

```
impl Add<Complex<usize>> for Interval {
    type Output = GenericInterval<Complex<usize>>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Complex<usize>) -> Self::Output {
        GenericInterval(self.0 + rhs, self.1 + rhs)
    }
}
```

In action: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57c2a08aa19d60a997309cd4b164a776

Comment: Actually I think your example is a very good point. In C++ we have non-member functions (operators) to be able to implement the symmetric cases of `operator+(myType, int)` and `operator+(int, myType)`. Now since Rust doesn't have the concept of non-member functions (at least you can't define a non-member operator in the same way, I don't think) ... maybe the solution to that is this?

Comment: I am going to maybe have to think about this for a while, that might not do what I think it will do